# Array of QImage other than QImage::Format_Indexed8

Tags: arrays, qt, rgb, qimage

Until now I had a `QImage` with `QImage::Format_Indexed8`.
I fill the array with the needed color `data[y*width+x] = i` and everything works fine.

But now i need RGB instead of Indexed8 so I use `QImage::Format_RGB32`.

Allocating memory:

```
data = static_cast<unsigned char*>(malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*4*HEIGHT*WIDTH));
```

Filling array for `QImage`: `data[(y*width+x)*4] = QColor(i, 0, 0).value();`

Well, the image seems right, but it is dark blue instead of (lighter) red!
What is wrong? The calculating of the index or the color?

I am using Qt 4.8.6

Thank you!

### Update

```
data[(y*width+x)*4] = 0x00;
data[(y*width+x)*4+1] = 0x00;
data[(y*width+x)*4+2] = i;
data[(y*width+x)*4+3] = 0xFF;
```

This would work, so I think the problem of my first try must be, that I only wrote in first char and not all 4, but is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Since data is of type unsigned char, you cannot assign integers into directly.

```
    QColor(...).value();
```

returns int values. If you make data of type int, it will assign correctly.